# Converting UK times (both BST and GMT) represented as strings to UTC (in C#)

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I have to use some dates and times from a legacy database. They are represented as strings. Dates are dd/MM/yy. Times are HH:mm.

I'd like to convert these to UTC as soon as I pull them from the database. I'm working on US systems, so need a common time.

The problem I'm facing is how to convert them to UTC DateTime values. I can do the parsing, etc. The real problem I have concerns the timezone.

I'm trying to use the following approach:

```
DateTime ukTime = // Parse the strings in a DateTime value.
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInformation = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset utcTime = new DateTimeOffset(ukTime, timeZoneInformation.BaseUtcOffset);
```

However, this gives incorrect values if the date is in the British Summer Time period.

I can use "GMT Daylight Time" on those dates, but that requires me to know when the switchover is. I'm sure there must be a less laborious way.

As I'm not using a machine with UK time settings I can't rely on local time.

Basically, I need something like:

```
// Works for both GMT (UTC+0) and BST (UTC+1) regardless of the regional settings of the system it runs on.
DateTime ParseUkTimeAsUtcTime(string date, string time)
{
    ...
}
```

I've scoured the posts, but couldn't find anything that addressed this directly. Surely this is also an issue with EST, EDT, etc?

Comment: I need this as a generic TimeInTimeZone->TimeInUTC method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the [`GetUtcOffset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378.aspx) method on your `TimeZoneInfo` instance, which takes "adjustment rules" into consideration.

Using this should work basically the same as your original example, but you'll use that method instead of the `BaseUtcOffset` property.

```
DateTime ukTime = // Parse the strings in a DateTime value.
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInformation = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset utcTime = new DateTimeOffset(ukTime, timeZoneInformation.GetUtcOffset(ukTime));
```

Comment: Nice, but could you maybe post a code sample for the ignorant?  This should be a canonical resource.

Comment: I think this example should cover what you need to do.  Let me know if you've simplified this at all.

Comment: Only thing I would add to this, is that to get an actual DateTime object I referred to `utcTime.UtcDateTime`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString).ToUniversalTime();
```

Assuming that the database server stores its datetimes in the same timezone as your application server.